# Leaflet JS add GeoJSON shape as a hole in a polygon

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson

I have a dataset which already contains geojson. I can add it to my map with the following line of code.

```
L.geoJson(data.geojson).addTo(map);
```

And I get this
[image: geojson plotted on map]

But I want to achieve this, where the surrounding area is covered up and my geojson shape is a hole in the middle of it.

[image: geojson as a hole in the map]

According to [the leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon)

> You can also create a polygon with holes by passing an array of arrays of latlngs, with the first latlngs array representing the exterior ring while the remaining represent the holes inside.

So in theory something like:

```
var scotland = [[60,-13],[60,0],[50,4],[50,-13]];
L.Polygon([scotland,coordinatesOfShapeHole].addTo(map);
```

My problem is this function doesn't seem to like me passing in data.geojson or data.geojson.coordinates as the second parameter (coordinatesOfShapeHole);

Is there some way to convert data.geojson into a format the L.Polygon function is happy with?

Or alternatively do the same thing but with L.geoJson?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. Which version of Leaflet are you using?

Here, have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/wo060nos/) jsFiddle.

It is important you get the arrays right.

First array is the polygon object [ in here the outer ring [ in here some [lat,lon],[,] close the outer ring], then the inner ring [ in here some [lat,lon],[,] close the inner ring ] close the polygon ].

```
scotland = L.polygon([[[60,-13],[60,0],[50,4],[50,-13]],
                  [[55.7,-4.5],[56,-4.5],[56,-4],[55.7,-4]]]);
scotland.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hi thanks. That works great if I'm dealing with a straightforward polygon, but my data is in geojson format. Do you know if there's a way to convert the geojson into polygon coordinates. Or achieve it using L.geoJson?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. I forked the jsFiddle to use L.geoJson. http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/xa6vg5zj/

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I hadn't realised the geojson contained a polygon definition which can be passed a multi-array similar to the standard polygon.